# How do you use global variables or constant values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I have a program that looks like:

```
$offset = Point.new(100, 200);

def draw(point)
  pointNew = $offset + point;
  drawAbsolute(point)
end

draw(Point.new(3, 4));
```

the use of `$offset` seems a bit weird.

In C, if I define something outside of any function, it is a global variable automatically. Why in Ruby does it have to be `$offset` but cannot be `offset` and still be global?  If it is `offset`, then it is a local?  But local to where, because it feels very much global.

Are there better ways to write the code above?  The use of `$offset` may seem a bit ugly at first.

---

Update:  I can put this offset inside a `class` definition, but what if two or several classes need to use this constant? In this case do I still need to define an `$offset`?

Comment: Coming from C you might not know this, but you don't need to put semi colons on the end of your lines in Ruby. You only need to use ; to separate multiple statements on the same line e.g. "a = 5; b = 10"

Answer (score 54, accepted):

One thing you need to realize is in Ruby everything is an object. Given that, if you don't define your methods within `Module` or `Class`, Ruby will put it within the `Object` class. So, your code will be local to the `Object` scope.

A typical approach on Object Oriented Programming is encapsulate all logic within a class:

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  # If we don't specify coordinates, we start at 0.
  def initialize(x = 0, y = 0)
    # Notice that `@` indicates instance variables.
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  # Here we override the `+' operator.
  def +(point)
    Point.new(self.x + point.x, self.y + point.y)
  end

  # Here we draw the point.
  def draw(offset = nil)
    if offset.nil?
      new_point = self
    else
      new_point = self + offset 
    end
    new_point.draw_absolute
  end

  def draw_absolute
    puts "x: #{self.x}, y: #{self.y}"
  end
end

first_point = Point.new(100, 200)
second_point = Point.new(3, 4)

second_point.draw(first_point)
```

Hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: +1 for the refactoring. With respect to top-level code being local to the `Object` scope: that's true for variables without the `$` prefix, but, by contrast, _methods_ you put there _are_ global (while also becoming private members of the `Object` class).

Comment: so I think in my case, if all `Point` objects are with respect to a certain constant offset, then I can have an offset (x, y) as a class constant, so the `draw_absolute()` will use this class constant as an offset

Answer (score 113):

Variable scope in Ruby is controlled by sigils to some degree. Variables starting with `$` are global, variables with `@` are instance variables, `@@` means class variables, and names starting with a capital letter are constants. All other variables are locals. When you open a class or method, that's a new scope, and locals available in the previous scope aren't available.

I generally prefer to avoid creating global variables. There are two techniques that generally achieve the same purpose that I consider cleaner:

1. Create a constant in a module. So in this case, you would put all the classes that need the offset in the module `Foo` and create a constant `Offset`, so then all the classes could access `Foo::Offset`.
2. Define a method to access the value. You can define the method globally, but again, I think it's better to encapsulate it in a module or class. This way the data is available where you need it and you can even alter it if you need to, but the structure of your program and the ownership of the data will be clearer. This is more in line with OO design principles.

Answer (score 10):

One of the reasons why the global variable needs a prefix (called a "sigil") is because in Ruby, unlike in C, you don't have to declare your variables before assigning to them. The sigil is used as a way to be explicit about the scope of the variable.

Without a specific prefix for globals, given a statement `pointNew = offset + point` inside your `draw` method then `offset` refers to a local variable inside the method (and results in a `NameError` in this case). The same for `@` used to refer to instance variables and `@@` for class variables.

In other languages that use explicit declarations such as `C`, `Java` etc. the placement of the declaration is used to control the scope.

Comment: How does the `$` help Ruby know if this is a new variable or an existing one? If you assign something to `$foo` thinking that it's some existing `$foo`, but it happens that there isn't any `$foo` yet, or there was but someone has removed it, then Ruby will create `$foo` as a new global nevertheless, despite it's not the same `$foo` you have thought. `$` will not repair the lack of proper declarations.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's local to the file you declared offset. Consider every file to be a method itself.

Maybe put the whole thing into a class and then make offset a class variable with `@@offset = Point.new(100, 200);`?

Comment: No, a local variable is **not** local to a file, but to the innermost block in which it is declared.