# How can I declare a global variable in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I declare a global variable in Ruby on Rails?

My sample code:

in my `controller#application.rb`:

```
def user_clicked()
  @current_userid = params[:user_id]
end
```

in my `layout#application.html.haml`
I have sidebar with this link:

```
= link_to "John", user_clicked_path(:user_id => 1)
= link_to "Doe", user_clicked_path(:user_id => 2)
= link_to "View clicked user", view_user_path
```

in my `views#view_user.html.haml`:

```
%h2 @current_userid
```

I want to declare a global variable that can modify my controller and use it anywhere, like controller, views, and etc. The above is only a sample scenario. If I click the John or Doe link, it will send a `user_id` to the controller and when I click the "View clicked user" link, it will display the last clicked link. It is either `John=1` or `Doe=2`.

Of course if I click the "View clicked user" link first, it will display `nil`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112765/how-to-reference-global-variables-and-class-variables)

Comment: Hi... Sorry for my bad grammar ^_^ I edited my question ^_^ and sample scenario. What I am trying to say is I want a global variable that I can access anywhere. like the example above, if I clicked John or Doe link, it will send a user_id to the controller and when I click the "View clicked user" link, it will display the last clicked link, it is either John=1 or Doe=2. Ofcourse if I clicked "View clicked user" link first, it will display nil. ^_^ Please help ^_^

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Ruby global variables are declared by prefixing the identifier with `$`

```
$foo = 'bar'
```

Which you rarely see used for [a number of reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil). And it's not really what you are looking for.

In Ruby instance variables are declared with `@`:

```
class DemoController
  def index
    @some_variable = "dlroW olleH"
    @some_variable = backwards
  end
  private 
  def backwards
     @some_variable.reverse
  end
end
```

Rails automatically passes the controller's instance variables to the view context.

```
# /app/views/demos/index.html.haml
%h1= @some_variable
```

Guess what it outputs and I'll give you a cookie.

In your example `@global_variable` is nil since `controller#sample_1` is not called - the request would go through  `controller#sample_2`.

```
def sample_2
  @global_variable = "Hello World"
end
```

Comment: Hi... Thank you for the reply ^_^ I edited my question above ^_^ and change the sample scenario. What I am trying to say is I want a global variable that I can access anywhere. If I clicked John or Doe link, it will send a user_id to the controller and when I click the "View clicked user" link, it will display the last clicked link, it is either John=1 or Doe=2. Ofcourse if I clicked "View clicked user" link first, it will display nil. Sorry for my bad grammar ^_^

Comment: I think what you are looking for may be sessions http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: Thanks for this sessions ^_^... I tried and I am using it now everywhere... session[:global_variable]