# Accesing environment variables with $ and ENV in ruby

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, env

I am trying to acces an environment variable set in ~/.bashrc

In ~/.bashrc I have set

```
export testdata = <some path>
```

without the <> of course.
I may add that I also tried adding

```
testdata=<some path>
```

to /etc/environment

When I am still in the shell I can do

```
echo $testdata
```

which gives  as result
When in my script I can do

```
puts ENV['testdata']
```

which will print 
So far so good. However I another script that was not written by me where there is a line like

```
if $testdata then
#some code
end
```

which is supposed to just execute the code when the environment varaible is set. However this code is not working for me. Only when I replace $ with ENV[] the code is correclty executed.

Comment: Variables prefixed with $ are not environment variables in Ruby, they're global variables. Do `$testdata = ENV['testdata']` if you need that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `$var` is a  [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112765/how-to-reference-global-variables-and-class-variables) in Ruby, and not an environment variable. To access environment variable, as you said, you need to use `ENV['var']`.

Comment: and global variables would have to be set in the same script or could they possibly be set by an external script?

Comment: What do you mean by external script?

Comment: Assuming my script as described above is in test.rb. If I have a script do_test.rb that called test.rb. Could do_test.rb set global variables for use in test.rb?

Comment: If your program `require`s several ruby files, then global variables maybe set anywhere in those files and they will become available when ruby interpreter encounters them.

Comment: Absolutely. Just make sure to define variables first and then require your test.rb.

Comment: thx for the answer. I might just have to get back to the original author and see if he has anything of the sort that I am missing