# Retrieve values in hash in hash

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

I have a hash like this:

```
$login_form = {
    $username => {web_element_type: :id, web_element: 'uname'},
    $password => {web_element_type: :id, web_element: 'pass'}
}
```

How can i retrieve $password's web element type and web element with the simplest way?

Comment: I would suggest you to go read some intro on ruby syntax. Ruby differs from PHP. One can not simply expect the syntax of one language will be applied everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

## Global variables ?

Are you sure you need [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042384/how-do-you-use-global-variables-or-constant-values-in-ruby)?

Right now, the keys in your hash aren't string, symbol or integers, but the object referenced by the variables `$username` and `$password`. Those variables are global, and are accessible from everywhere in your code. This doesn't seem to be a good idea for a variable called `password`.

If those variables aren't initialized, they both are `nil`, so your `login_form` is actually :

```
{nil=>{:web_element_type=>:id, :web_element=>"pass"}}
```

The values for `$username` have been overwritten by `$password`.

If you're sure that `login_form` should be a global variable :

```
$login_form = {
    username: {web_element_type: :id, web_element: 'uname'},
    password: {web_element_type: :id, web_element: 'pass'}
}

p $login_form[:password].values_at(:web_element_type,  :web_element)
#=> [:id, "pass"]
type, element = $login_form[:password].values_at(:web_element_type,  :web_element)
p type
#=> :id
p element
#=> "pass"
```

If not, you could use `@login_form` or just `login_form`.

If you're still confused, you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495098/difference-between-various-variables-scopes-in-ruby).

Comment: I tried it but it didn't solve. E.g: If i retrieve $username's value, it even retrieving to $password's values.

Comment: See update about global variables.

Comment: “You need to first get the value for `$password`, which is a Hash.`—this is wrong, please remove.

Comment: That is just a collection of web elements and i need them reachable. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work:(

Comment: @mudasobwa: I don't think it's wrong : `$password` is a (weird) key in this case, and it has an associated value in `$login_form` hash.

Comment: @mudasobwa: It isn't wrong if `$username` and `$password` are initialized, it's just really weird. Still, I removed it to avoid adding confusion.

Comment: @EricDuminil Sorry, I ran into troubles parsing php syntax with ruby parser :) It’s not wrong, it should work if all global variables, used as keys, were previously set.

Answer (score 1):

This solution can help you and ready [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html)

define hash like this way

```
$login_form = {
  :username => {web_element_type: :id, web_element: 'uname'},
  :password => {web_element_type: :id, web_element: 'pass'}
}
```

you can retrieve `password` like this way

```
$login_form[:password]
```

If you have any question please me know.

Comment: I have a question : why did you post this answer, when the exact same content has been posted half an hour before?